# In SQL Server, if I have three columns, can one be displayed as rows, one as columns and the third as the intersecting results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have gotten to the point where my query will display the UserName, Date and a Count of records for that date per user but it is displayed in this format.

To get here it is just grouping by the User and Date:

```
User  | Date | COUNT
Name1 | 3-19 | 5
Name2 | 3-19 | 6
Name3 | 3-19 | 1
Name1 | 3-20 | 2
Name2 | 3-20 | 7
Name3 | 3-20 | 8
```

Is it possible to display the results so that the Users are the rows and the dates for that range are the columns with the counts filling in the intersections?

```
        3-19    3-20
Name1   5       2
Name2   6       7
Name3   1       8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using [PIVOT in SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) as in this [DBFIDDLE Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/iwTX_a7M)

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT [User], Date, [Count]
    FROM your_table
) AS MainTable([User], Date, [Count])
PIVOT (
    SUM([Count])
    FOR Date IN ([3-19], [3-20])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Output :

```
User    3-19    3-20
Name1      5    2
Name2      6    7
Name3      1    8
```

Please make sure to surround [User] and [Count] column_names with square brackets as these are reserved keywords in sql-server

Update :

> is it possible to make the "FOR Date IN..." apply to the date range I
> am using without needing to type out each date? Can it use the results
> of another select statement which would distinctly provide the dates
> in the range?

Yes, It's possible using FOR XML PATH as in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/FaBvJF6q).

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Date) 
                      FROM your_table
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');


SET @query = 'SELECT *
              FROM (
                  SELECT [User], Date, [Count]
                  FROM your_table
              ) AS MainTable([User], Date, [Count])
              PIVOT (
                  SUM([Count])
                  FOR Date IN (' + @cols + ')
              ) AS PivotTable;'

EXECUTE(@query);
```

This also shall give you the expected output.

Comment: The example you provided resolves most of the issues but is it possible to make the "FOR Date IN..." apply to the date range I am using without needing to type out each date?  Can it use the results of another select statement which would distinctly provide the dates in the range?

Comment: Hi @CharlesBatschelet; Did you had chance to check my updated answer. Please let me know, if I can help you further

Comment: It appears to work and I can hopefully handle it from here.  Thank you!